# Wordpress <li> on sidebar

Tags: php, html, wordpress, html-lists

This is my site http://appsource.biz/paceline/?page_id=46

As you can see the Recent, Popular and random tabs are misaligned. There is something wrong with the `<li>`. I dont know whats wrong with the `<li>` in my site but this has the same exact code from here http://www.elegantthemes.com/preview/TheSource/about-2/

I think theres something wrong with the LI internally please help

Comment: Isolate your problem to a small code sample and post it to jsfiddle.net

Answer (score 0):

You have given the width to

```
#sidebar #firstcol {
    width: 160px;
```

remove this everything will be aligned properly...

Remember You need to take care of your divs floating below

Answer (score 0):

You have close the "onecol" id in wrong place.

```
This your code.
<div id="sidebar">
<div id="onecol"></div> <!-- end #onecol -->
<div id="firstcol">
Please remove this tags "</div> <div id="firstcol">"
```

Thanks.